# What is the average migrate time from SVN to GIT using Subgit

Tags: git, svn, migration, subgit

I would like to use subgit to migrate all branches, tags and trunks from svn to git. What is average time it takes to import everything from svn to git using subgit?

Comment: What is the average time to transfer cargo from a bus to a plane?

Answer (score 2):

In my experiments, it takes about 8 minutes to translate SQLJet sources (~1300 revisions) and about an hour to translate a repository with 10000 revisions, so **150-160** revisions per minute would be a good starting estimate.

If you're using svn+ssh protocol, it would take about 1.5x more time.

Of course translation time depends on repository structure and amount of changes in average revisions and some other factors.

I'm one of SubGit developers.